# Extract Row Locations to Use as Reference

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I populated an excel sheet with the locations of blank cells in my sheet using suggestions from [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767296/excel-list-of-blank-cells) So I have a Column A filled with locations in the following format

`$X$1` or `$X2:$X$4`.

What I am trying to do is use those row numbers from the column explain above to populate a separate column. I want to use the row numbers as a reference in what to populate for the column. So a Column B looking something like

`=$B$1` or `=$B$2:$B$4` *(took 1 and 2-4 and used it as row number for reference call)*

*Both columns are referencing a different sheet so please excuse any column naming.*

I'm not sure if this is going to require VBA or if I can get away with just using a formula, I expect VBA due to desired specifics. I've looked at post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979935/extract-number-from-a-string-of-text-excel) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771802/extract-number-from-string-in-vba). But neither of these fully encompass what I'm looking for. Especially since I want it to express all the contents in a `$B$2:$B$4` case.

My intuition on how to solve this problem tells me, parse the string from Column A for the 1st number then check if it's the end of the string. If it is, feed it to the reference that populates Column B, if not then find the 2nd number and go through a loop that populates the cell (would prefer to keep all the content in one cell in this case) with each value for each reverence.

*i.e.*

`=$B2`

`=$B3`

`=$B4`

My question is how do I go about this? How do I parse the string? How do I generate the loop that will go through the necessary steps? Such as using the number as a reference to pull information from a different column and feed it neatly into yet another column.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? How to populate another column? What did you try? Not quite sure what you're trying to do. Are you using a formula and you want to drag it to use in another column, that's not Col. A?

Comment: "locations of blank cells", "I want it to express all the contents in a $B$2:$B$4 case" - what contents?

Comment: There's some clarifying context missing from your question.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I think you need to step back and explain in plain words what you want to achieve. What is the data? What is the expected result? Don't get hung up on the approach with this reference formula. You are overcomplicating things and shooting off in a completely wrong direction. Edit your question and leave a comment when you've done that.

Comment: Sorry guys, tried to elaborate more with my edit. Let me know how I can better explain the problem.

Comment: I think you want the INDIRECT function: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm

Comment: As for what I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to use the row numbers found in Column A, to populate Column B the value of Column X at the same row number. While going through every element in cases where the text in Column A expresses a range.

Comment: I think INDIRECT is promising but I'm not sure how to get it to only give me the row numbers. When it shows $X$1 I just want the 1, because I want the cell to contain the value of "Sheet2"$N$1.

Comment: If it's 3 cells instead of one, then how should the output look?

Comment: The value of "Sheet2"$N$1

Comment: "I want it to express all the contents in a $B$2:$B$4 case" - how should these 3 cells be "expressed"?  Is the output going into a single cell ?  If Yes then how are the values to be combined?

Comment: @TimWilliams I simply want the single cell to list all three values. For example, if I have a cell that contains the value $B$2:$B$4 then I want to populate the cell with the value of $X2, $X3, $X4, preferably with newlines between them.

Answer (score 1):

If (for example) you have an address of $X2:$X$4 then

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = yourSheetReference.Range("$X2:$X$4")
```

If you want to map that to the same rows but column B then

```
Set rng = rng.Entirerow.Columns(2)
```

will do that.  note: it's not so clear from your question whether you're mapping X>>B or B>>X.

Once you have the range you want you can loop over it:

```
For Each c in rng.Cells
    'do something with cell "c"
next c
```

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, c As Range, rng As Range, c2, v, sep

    Set shtSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<< source data sheet

    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("A2") '<<range addresses start here

    'process addresses until ColA is empty
    Do While c.Value <> ""
        'translate range to (eg) Column X
        Set rng = shtSrc.Range(c.Value).EntireRow.Columns(24)
        sep = ""
        v = ""
        'build the value from the range
        For Each c2 In rng.Cells
            v = v & sep & c2.Value
            sep = vbLf
        Next c2
        c.Offset(0, 1) = v '<< populate in colB
   Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I go about this with dynamic ranges? The ranges that I'm interested in vary. The ranges are listed in a column but I'm only interested in the row. What I'm trying to do is pull the row number from a value in Column B and using it to pull the value from Column X at the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim fRng As Range ' the cell that has the formula
    Set fRng = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
    Dim tWS As Worksheet 'the worksheet that has the values you want to get
    Set tWS = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range(fRng.Formula).Rows
     'Debug.Print r.Row ' this is the rows numbers
     Debug.Print tWS.Cells(r.Row, "N").Value 'N is the column name
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I go about this for dynamic ranges? I have a lists of ranges that I'm interested in, with lots of jumps between them.

Comment: Set `fRng` to your dynamic range, then loop through all cells in this range.

Comment: How do I set it as a dynamic range?

Comment: I think [@TimWilliams answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43989952/4039286) will do what you want, my answer is just an idea of how to get rows from formula.